# How to put borders around rows in jQuery Mobile

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile

I'm making use of the table-reflow on my HTML tables. I'm simply looking to put borders around  the rows in the table. When I inspected the element via Chrome and see that jQuery Mobile appends the following class to the table:

```
ui-responsive table-stroke ui-table ui-table-reflow
```

Thus I looked to add the following style:

```
.ui-responsive .table-stroke .ui-table .ui-table-reflow tr
{
  border-style:solid;
  border-width:5px;
}
```

But some how I still don't get border around the rows, regardless of the screen size. Any ideas how I could achieve this

Comment: Try adding `!important` sometimes custom styles are overridden by default styles.

Comment: Just tried that now and no such luck

Comment: Try adding styles to `td`. Edit: check this https://developer.mozilla.org/samples/cssref/border-collapse.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume from your description that you only want borders around the rows at full width and not the individual cells, and then when the table reflows you again want borders around each row (which are actually cells displayed on separate rows).

If so here is a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/e92p7/)**

In the CSS, the media query is for when the table is viewed on wider screens. In this case we give the TR (rows) a border and set the cell borders to 0.  When the screen is narrow and the table reflows, the TR border is 0, and the TD borders are set.  You should play with the CSS in the demo to get what you want.

```
.ui-table tr {
    border: 0px solid rgb(51,51,51);
}
.ui-table-reflow.ui-responsive td, .ui-table-reflow.ui-responsive th {
    border: 2px solid rgb(51,51,51);
    border-left:4px solid rgb(51,51,51);
    border-right:4px solid rgb(51,51,51);
}
.ui-table-reflow.ui-responsive td:first-child, .ui-table-reflow.ui-responsive th:first-child {
    border-top:4px solid rgb(51,51,51);
}
.ui-table-reflow.ui-responsive td:last-child, .ui-table-reflow.ui-responsive th:last-child {
    border-bottom:4px solid rgb(51,51,51);
}


@media ( min-width: 35em ) {
    .ui-table tr {
        border: 4px solid rgb(51,51,51);
    }

    .ui-table-reflow.ui-responsive td, .ui-table-reflow.ui-responsive th {
         border: 0;
    }
}
```